# Get the adjacent indexes from the linear indexing in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Given a set of linear indexes of a matrix, how can I get only the adjacent indexes from it ?.  By adjacent I meant the indexes which are either on the left, right, top, bottom or diagonal position of an index.

For example, given a 4*5 matrix

```
B = [1 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 0 1 1;
     0 0 1 0 1;
     1 0 1 0 0;]
```

and the linear indices of B [1, 2, 4, 6, 11, 12, 14, 18, 19] (it corresponds to the indexes of non-zero entreies), how can I select only the one which have at least one neighbour ?  In this case, my input is

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 11, 12, 14, 18, 19]
```

I want the output to be

```
[1, 2, 6, 11, 12, 14, 18, 19]
```

as except 4, all others have neighbours in the index set.

Comment: Sounds like some form of an adjacency matrix. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277541/construct-adjacency-matrix-in-matlab) for hints.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2D-convolution to compute the number of non-zero neighbours of each entry, and use that as a logical mask:

```
result = find(B & conv2(B~=0, [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1], 'same'));
```

Comment: You got my +1 because this doesn't require toolboxes.

Answer (score 0):

The [`bwconncomp`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) function from the Image Processing Toolbox returns connected components in binary images. As your matrix is a binary image, i.e. a 2-D matrix containing zeros and ones, we can use this.

Calling the function

```
>> CC = bwconncomp(B);
```

returns a struct containing (among other fields) `PixelIdxList`, which is a cell array, where each element is an array of pixel indices corresponding to a specific connected component. In your case, this is:

```
>> CC.PixelIdxList

ans =

  1×2 cell array

    {8×1 double}    {[4]}
```

So you have two connected components: one consisting of 8 pixels, with indices given by `CC.PixelIdxList{1}`, and a second one containing 1 pixel with index `4`.

As you want to remove all pixels that have no neighbors, you can check all elements of `CC.PixelIdxList` for their number of elements and remove all with only one elements:

```
>> numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
>> toRemove = (numPixels == 1);
```

This gives us an array `toRemove` containing a `0` for each connected component we want to keep, and a `1` for each connected component we want to remove. Finally, you can concatenate all connected components you want to keep into a single array with

```
>> allIdx = CC.PixelIdxList(~tooSmall);
>> allIdx = allIdx{:};
```

which leaves us with the desired result

```
>> allIdx

allIdx =

     1
     2
     6
    11
    12
    14
    18
    19
```